# mySql trigger not working as intended

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables set up with a trigger, such that an insertion upon one table, will trigger an increment in the column of the second table at the same primary key (as both tables a linked by a foreign key), however at the moment the increment only once, then it does not increment for any subsequent insertions. My thinking is that it's probably with the way I set up the keys but I'm unsure, could someone please shed some light on this:

```
CREATE TABLE Members(
    ID  INT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    FIRST_NAME  TEXT(16),
    LAST_NAME  TEXT(16),
    TITLE  TEXT(7), /** 7 CHARS for  'Student'*/
    INSTITUTION  VARCHAR(2048),
    No_Publications INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
  );

CREATE TABLE Papers(
    ISBN  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Title  TEXT(4),
    Publish_Date  DATE NOT NULL,
    Topic  TEXT(128),
    PRIMARY KEY(ISBN)
  );

CREATE TABLE Publications(
    Author_ID  INT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ISBN  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (Author_ID, ISBN),
    FOREIGN KEY(Author_ID) REFERENCES Members(ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(ISBN) REFERENCES Papers(ISBN) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE /**Used in
    many to many relations*/
  );

  CREATE TRIGGER New_Publication AFTER INSERT ON Publications
  FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE Members SET No_Publications = No_Publications + 1
  WHERE Members.ID = Publications.Author_ID;
```

EDIT: I want the No_Publications to increase with insertion upon the publications table

EDIT 2: After implementing the `NEW` keyword the auto-incrementation now works however now the following occurs:

Upon adding 1 new paper to 1 new member, the paper is registered in the database, however, subsequent additions of papers to the same member are not registered, despite and increment occuring in the members table.

Insertion into the Publications table occurs as a result of the papers table which has been appended above for transparency.

Comment: Are any of your `Members` going to have so many `Publications`, or that datum going to be queried so frequently, that there is some (speed vs. size) reason to store the count redundantly, instead of just doing `select count(*) from Publications where Author_ID = whateverID` whenever you need that information?

Comment: @underscore_d are you saying that i should do a separte SELECT query to manually increment the column?

Comment: Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers; they are not case-sensitive. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: 'Insertion into the Publications table occurs as a result of the papers table'  - no it  doesn't you need to insert to the publications table.

Comment: @P.Salmon in the sense that; the publications table will only receive insert if a paper has been published

Comment: Why would author_id be unique in publications?

Comment: @P.Salmon you might've hit the nail on the head there

Comment: No might about it.

Comment: @Adrian No, I was asking why you need a column to increment in the 1st place - i.e. why, when you could simply just ask the DBMS to `count()` the number of rows in `Publications` for a given `Member` ID whenever you need that information, you instead feel the need to use space to store, & lines of code (a maintenance cost) to produce, a redundant copy of said count. There are situations where that's legitimate, usually due to intense performance pressures that'd make aggregating on-demand slower than desired, but there's no indication you have any, so aggregating is the default way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger should be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER New_Publication AFTER INSERT ON Publications 
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE Members SET No_Publications = No_Publications + 1 
WHERE Members.ID = NEW.Author_ID;
```

Even though his column should be updated also on deletes and having this column goes agains [database normalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) as you can get this information without having the column so it can be only useful in certain cases to improve performance and avoid counts.

Comment: this solved the issue, however now the Publications table does not register another publication, it only registers the first one associated with the id but the relevant column in members in incremented

Comment: @adrian examples please.